# How to display a specific setting or another if a shared setting value is present or not?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-settings

I'm trying to add some API integration to my app and i want to add a way to connect or disconnect from my settings app. So if the token isn't present in Shared Preferences the settings would display "Login to xxx" but if it exits then show "Logout from xxx".
example:

```
<Preference
        android:key="pref_connect_to_xxx"
        android:title="login to xxx" >

          />
```

But if the token is present i want to display

```
 <Preference
        android:key="pref_connect_to_xxx"
        android:title="logout from xxx" >

          />
```

Any idea about how to do this?

Comment: You described it pretty clearly, now what is it that you're looking for ? an example of how to use Shared Preferences ?

Comment: I know how to get the values from Shared Preferences, but i want to know how to set one value or another on the settings fragment as this is displayed from the XML.

Comment: The question is still unclear to me - sounds like a simple if-else...

Comment: Sorry i think im being unclear... I want to display login or logout in the settings activity but i don't know how to do it as it's defined in the XML.  <Preference
        android:key="pref_connect_xxx"
        android:title="Log in to xxx" > />

Comment: Sounds to me like you should have a LoginActivity which should simply get skipped (call your main-activity directly instead of going through "login" screen) when the relevant attribute in SharedPreferences is already set.

Comment: I just edited the question with an example as i don't know how to dynamically change it from the code

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, then the following should solve your issue:

```
if (tokenAlreadySet()) {
    Preference connectToXXX = (Preference) findPreference("pref_connect_to_xxx");
    connectToXXX.setSummary("logout from xxx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the summary programmatically by finding the preference by its key and, depending on the token being set or not in your `SharedPreferences`, show one text or another in the summary.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean token = prefs.getInt("token",-1) == -1?false:true;

Preference pref = (Preference) findPreference("pref_connect_to_xxx");                   
           pref.setSummary(token?"Logout":"Login");
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you are saving a token to the shared preferences, and if it isn't there, you want to treat the user as not logged in?

Checkout the documentation on SharedPreferences: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Most `get` methods on the object, including `getString` has a default value. So you could do: `String token = getString(tokenKey, "");` and then check it like: `if(token.isEmpty())...`

Comment: i edited the question as the value is in the XML and i don't know how to dynamically change it from the code.